# HTML5 rendering differences

Tags: html, element

i have table tag with border='1' attribute as source html.

it gives a different table out in IE8, and different in Chrome latest version.

border is different in style.

Why is such big difference and how can i achieve a consistent look and feel across different browsers?

Comment: I cant believe this question is from 2017. Consistent look across browsers has been such a problem and concern that multiple HTML5/CSS/JS have been proposed trying to address this issue. Try googling about cross-browser compatibility and you will find material to read for the next couple of years. Find a framework that you like and use it.

Comment: Google "css reset"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the frustration called web development and the inconsistency that comes with that.

> Why is such big difference

The HTML5 and css RFC has a technical definition of every feature of the language, but it is not specific enough. Thus, it resulted in different browsers having different implementations of this language and therefore you'll notice slight variations that can break entire layouts. Also, often browsers implement features that are not officially supported by the language RFC, so those are not supported by other browsers.

> how can i achieve a consistent look and feel across different browsers

Often you'll have to explicitly add properties to your style sheet to get rid of default styles. You can choose to limit yourself to features that are officially supported. Or you can create custom elements like custom dropdown menus and such.